# Looking for some feedback on my first project!?

Tags: feedback, sound-design, movie-trailers, mixing, design

Hey guys just looking for some feedback and critical comments. This is one of my first projects in school. Rip me apart let me know everything I could do to make it better. Thanks!
Heres the link:

http://vimeo.com/33840492

Answer (score 1):

Really good. Only comment I would say is to maybe include a few more sections of sound as it would be in the film. The use of sound effects and monologue was very technical and impressive, typical of a hollywood trailer but on their own it became slightly monotonous by the end.

Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

Good work, your scoring sounded pretty appropriate for the trailer, and i did feel an ebb and flow of tension, which is like the backbone of good sound design.

The first thing that i felt could have been improved is the build-up at the end. It sounded like you went for the whole crazy buildup and cut that many trailers climax with. I felt that it didn't build up enough, and the silence at the end could be made more powerful with a bigger, crazier crescendo before it.

You had some pretty good wolf vocalisations, but i felt that they were a bit reserved; maybe you could bring them out more. I'm not presuming that this is what you've done, but i used to find that when i wasn't totally happy with an effect i'd created, i had a tendency to push it down in the mix. This is a mistake. Your key FX need to really stand out, especially in action and suspense sequences.

Also, i think the trailer would have benefited from more details. It's time consuming, but good sound design comes, in part, from all the little (and big) aural details. Some are more important than others, but it's not always clear which is which until you've auditioned them.

All in all, nice work. And good on you for posting an example for the world to critique! No one ever got good at anything by doing it perfectly the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great result for an early project and it sounds like you're in the right place. Having said that, here are a few tips for your consideration.

The wolves sounded like they could use a little boost in the lower end to beef them up a little and attenuation on the high end to localize them more. Another trick is to duplicate the sound on another track, pitch the duplicate down about an octave and then you can blend that in. Be sure to keep an ear out for artifacting with vocal sounds like the wolves. This is also a good trick to use sparingly on percussive hits.

Another thing that I heard was some clipping. It didn't sound like you were over-driving the digital channels, but it was more in the breaks in sound. I noticed it in some of the dialog, score and effect sounds. Make sure that you have small fades on both the top and tail end of the sound regions just a few milliseconds will do. Another trick if you want to have a fluttering effect like you did with what sounded like a hawk sound and in the score during the dissonant crescendo towards the end is side-chain dynamic processing. There are two approaches to it, depending on your desired result. One is to have the sound go through a gate and send a signal to the side-chain of the gate to allow the gate to open. The other approach is to do the same thing, but with a compressor, so that the level is attenuated by the side-chain signal and then have a gate after that. Either approach, make sure you adjust your attack and release times to loose the clipping at the open and close points. The first approach would probably be the one to give you the result you would want for this particular approach.

I hope you find these tips useful. Good luck with your future endeavors!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the feedback well appreciated I'll be posting more soon keep the constructive criticism coming!

Answer (score 0):

Hey NAS,

For a first project I thought this was pretty good! The main thing that stood out for me that needs work is the use of ambience: I felt this should have been applied more so, particularly in the second half of the video. It worked fine without ambience up until 00:41 where Liam Neeson is in the snow at which point you bring it in. I felt from then on though you should have kept the ambiences (albeit at a lower vol level than the ice winds) as after having it in it then becomes very obvious without it in the mix. Having it there would help bring the audience in and increase the intensity of the heighten scenes towards the end of the clip.

Hope that helps, once again though good job!